# Delphi component spTbxToolbar skin change

Tags: delphi, components, skinning

How to change at runtime by code (not for groupskintype), the skin type for a sptbxtoolbar component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change the skin of all SpTBXLib components at once.

Use this code

```
SkinManager.SetSkin('Office 2007 Blue');
```

You can however set for each SpTBXLib component if it is drawed using the skin, Windows look or the default look, by setting assigning the `SkinType` property.

```
MyComponent.SkinType := sknWindows;
```

**Hint:** Toolbars itself do not have the SkinType property. They are always drawn using the skin.

Comment: Hi DR, I have a main spTbxToolbar, if I put the code 
     SkinManager.SetSkin('Office 2007 Blue');

The toolbar still present default skin, the property SkinType not present in the spxtoolbar,like the spxStatusBar.

Comment: Thanks DR, with your comment, I revisited my form, and after delete some components (I think this component cause some type of problem with the skin manager) the code function very well. Thanks again.

Comment: Erangel: if you found DR's answer to be helpful and appropriate, it's customary to "accept" the answer by ticking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that component, but found [this](http://www.mytreedb.com/downloads/m-subcat/a-skins.html) with Google.  Hope it helps.