# Delphi - how to skin a form

Tags: delphi, skin

I just finish reading [delphi-skinning-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969847/delphi-skinning-libraries) and [sptbxtoolbar-skin-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815371/delphi-component-sptbxtoolbar-skin-change) but this is not what I wanted. I'm interested in how to apply a skin on a form, just like the classic WinAmp windows :)
Any aricle or code or ideea is welcomed.

I just found [Windows XP Theme Manager](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=17&Itemid=33), i'm at work now, so i'll study it at home (I hope this is wahat I need)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the former question (with a nudge at [VCLSkin](http://www.link-rank.com/)) is exactly what you need -- don't get suggested too much by the fact that all the examples look like MSWindows -- the skinning behind them allows for any image-based GUI.

The only alternative is ditching the Forms altogether and building your skin from ground up using WinAPI. An example can be seen on [flipcode](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Win32_Window_Skinning.shtml) (C++, but WinAPI's the same).

Comment: I want to know how it's done, so I can write my onw apps

Comment: @Remus, There you have it, I've extended my answer, VCLSkin basically substitutes skins for all your components using WinAPI.